# IE8 ignores margin-top any idea why?

Tags: html, css

i have two divs one floated to the left and the other to the right and after them i have added a div with style clear:both

after that i have an other div with a margin-top : 35px the margin is shown as expected in IE7 FF Chrome and opera but can't see it on IE8 any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from what you've posted but if the div giving you problems is empty, this could be an issue. If that is the case, try adding `&nbsp;` into it.

Comment: I would love an explanation too!  That was driving me crazy the other day.

Comment: I can't explain it but it's something with lots of people running into. It's not a new issue with IE - has been around for quite a while. http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=ie+empty+div+bug&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: An empty div doesn't take up any space, therefore doesn't count as something that needs 'spacing from' using margin

Comment: @Yassir: If this fixes the issue for you, could you mark it as answered so it doesn't show up in the Unanswered Questions list?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem the other day.  I'm not sure why it is occurring and I am far from an expert on the topic but to solve it I added padding bottom to the floated divs and it gave the same effect I was looking for.